# Nodejs Electron App can't find image path

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder

I'm trying to show an image on an electron app. I've included it via `extraResources` in `package.json` like that:

```
"extraResources": [
  {
    "from": "app/assets/images",
    "to": "../app/assets/images",
    "filter": [
      "**/*"
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm calling it from JavaScript like that:

```
./app/assets/images/a.jpg
```

But it's calling wrong path which is: `file:///D:/Program%20Files/nodejs/Nodejs_Projects/paletten4/release/win-unpacked/resources/app.asar/app/app/assets/images/a.jpg`

There is no app.asar folder in the resources.

How can I get this image?